# fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb1: No such file or directory

Tags: usb

I will great my own OS. When I load `hello.bin` to my USB using:

```
sudo dd if=hello.bin of=/dev/sdb1 bs=512 count=1
```

and test the bootable USB using Qemu with this command:

```
sudo qemu-system-i386 dev/sdb
```

the result is:

```
qemu-system-i386: Could not open 'dev/sdb': No such file or directory
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: It's `/dev/sdb`, not `dev/sdb`.

Answer (score 1):

**You are trying to perform very dangerous actions.

Any mistake here may cost very high.

You can lose your data.**

But please make sure that */dev/sdb* exists.
You can check all block devices with `sudo lsblk` and then continue using `dd`. Usually it is possible to write to the whole disk, not its partition (*sdb* instead of *sdb1*).

In qemu part you should use the full path:
`sudo qemu-system-i386  /dev/sdb`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the device name /dev/sdb not the partition label /dev/sdb1, the image file is a low level image of a disk and can contain multiple partitions that will be placed on /dev/sdb and labelled automatically.

Comment: Maybe the question was edited after this answer was posted, but presently: the question ***is already*** using `sdb`, not `sdb1`.